# How to know which hibernate jar tomcat is using?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have a Java project running in Tomcat server.There is a common jar which includes many other jar files including hibernate(A lower version of hibernate). In addition I have a separate hibernate jar which is latest. When my tomcat starts sometimes it takes the hibernate version inside the common jar file and sometimes the separate one.

I want to make sure it always refers to the latest hibernate jar. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: what build tool are you using?

Comment: Apache ant. It got fixed. I added a PreResources tag in context.xml and made tomcat refer to the latest hibernate jar first always